# What are the ferry options for getting from Sweden to Scotland?

Tags: ferries, scotland, scandinavia, north-sea

As [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35862/alternative-route-for-the-shut-down-harwich-esbjerg-ferry-route-by-car) points out the routes from Sweden and Denmark to Newcastle has been discontinued. Driving the whole way from Stockholm (for example) to Scotland is some 26 hours and geography suggests that there may be a ferry option parts of the way.

What I have come up with this far is the Gothenburg-Kiel ferry (a bit off when coming from Stockholm) and the Amsterdam-Newcastle ferry. Are these the two best options for combining driving with ferrying or are there more alternatives? (Apart from the freighter options already listed in the referenced question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There don't seem to be any ferry routes from Stockholm going West of Gdansk.

You can probably go to [Direct Ferries](http://www.directferries.co.uk/) to look at a fairly comprehensive list of major ferry operators around Europe.

The best I can figure here is Stockholm-> Gdansk drive to Amsterdam or Rotterdam and take a ferry to England then drive to Scotland.

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Stockholm/Aberdeen) also reports similar ferry routes.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Thanks to @Willeke for pointing me in the right direction:

There may again be ferries from [Esjberg to Harwich starting this summer](http://www.reginaline.dk).

Comment: There used to be a Denmark (Esjberg) to England (Harwich) ferry, which is shown on some sites. But I can not find details and even on the sites that show the line on the map I can not get time table details.

Comment: There may be again: http://www.reginaline.dk/timetable-uk.html  It seems to be seasonal.

Comment: +1 as you now have two completely different options for routes.

Comment: @Willeke Let's not get ahead of ourselves.  Regina ferry isn't running yet. :)

Comment: Via Gdansk is not an improvement compared to the route via Kiel. Then it would even be easier to drive all the way from Stockholm to Amsterdam.  Gdansk - Amsterdam ~ 1200 KM and Stockholm - Amsterdam ~1400 KM.

Comment: @AndréPeseur OP isn't asking for improvement.  Just other options.  There are currently no improvement available. without having to drive cross Sweden or cross Europe

Comment: He is *Are these the two best options (...)*

Comment: This Regina Line thing has never happened, which is not surprising.  You might want to edit it out of the question.