# Route from North Scotland to Stockholm with no air travel

Tags: driving, ferries, scotland, stockholm

My parents-in-law live near Skye in North Scotland. They are planning to come and visit us in Stockholm in the summer, but for medical reasons they are unable to fly. Their preferred alternative is to combine driving and the ferry, taking their car with them.

I have looked at some alternative routes that go via Holland/Germany, but I usually get confused by how many options there are. Can someone please give a route from Scotland to Stockholm using only driving and ferries that minimises the driving time as much as possible.

Comment: You can see a suggested road route on [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Island-of-Skye/Stockholm) via Eurotunnel (28 hours). There are also [ferry routes](https://ferrygogo.com/ferry-to-denmark-from-uk/) from Newcastle to Amsterdam, and from Hull to Rotterdam. AFAIK there are currently no ferries from UK across the North Sea to Sandinavia.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, just follow Google Maps recommendations. I have been driving from Marseille to Stokholm on, like your situation, two drivers. We switched driver every time we filled up gas. The "next" driver bought a coffee, while the previous driver took the pillow and went to sleep. Didn't even make proper stop for eating, just McDonald's drive-thru. Our only breaks ere 45 minutes on Puttgarden-Rødby and 20 minutes on Helsingør-Helsingborg. Just make sure you take every opportunity to sleep and you'll be fine.

Comment: If you are serious about minimising driving time, then you can apparently get a ferry from [Travemünde to Helsinki](https://www.finnlines.com/routes/travemunde-helsinki/), and then there are several ferries to Stockholm I believe.

Comment: I have reopened this question and closed the older one as duplicate, as this question had already gotten more and better answers. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48074/what-are-the-ferry-options-for-getting-from-sweden-to-scotland

Comment: There's some good news: the Newcastle-Bergen ferry is slated to reopen! It will make this journey a lot more feasible. The bad news is that it won't happen before 2026. https://www.thelocal.no/20220707/direct-ferry-link-between-england-and-norway-could-be-set-for-return/

Comment: @leftaroundabout Every so-often there are such proposals.  They rarely make it beyond the "we're looking for investors" stage.  It's a long way from "I'm looking for money because I want to start a new ferry line" to actually running a service.  I've become quite sceptical, and I'll want to see it before I believe it (and even seeing it, I'm not confident [Holland Norway Lines](https://hollandnorwaylines.com/) will survive very long).

Comment: @gerrit yeah... we'll have to wait and see. However, I am rather optimistic because (as the question illustrates) this is almost the only feasible flightless connection between the UK and Scandinavia. Before Brexit, this wasn't as compelling, but now there's a [bilateral free trade agreement between the UK and Norway](https://www.regjeringen.no/no/tema/naringsliv/handel/nfd---innsiktsartikler/frihandelsavtaler/partner-land/frihandelsavtale-med-storbritannia2/id2723521/). Also of course _flygskam_.

Comment: There were plans to reopen the Edinburgh-Belgium ferry in Summer 2023, but no updates on that yet. That would decrese the travel a bit as you don't need to go all the way down to Newcastle. Source https://www.euronews.com/travel/2022/11/08/scotland-europe-ferry-service-to-restart-from-next-year-but-theres-a-catch

Comment: Are you sure someone unable to fly for medical reasons can sustain a 30+ hour car journey?

Comment: The post-Brexit UK/Norway trade deal is less than the situation before Brexit, so it's unlikely to lead to significantly more demand for ferries than there was in the 2010's. There are also already freight ferries from the UK to Scandinavia, they just don't take cars or foot passengers.

Comment: Having done a trip like that, @d-b, 1/3 the way across the US (1500 miles, 24 hours to the minute), it's fine for young folk (we were in our early 20s). However, for someones parents who are unable to fly _for medical reasons_, that's a pretty unrealistic suggestion. Also, by the time we were at hour 22, we were both so exhausted that we were stopping at almost every interstate off-ramp to swap drivers.

Comment: @JonathanReez, depends on the medical reason.  I've got relatives who are otherwise medically fit, but who develop altitude sickness at just 6000 feet elevation (airliner cabins are normally pressurized to 8000 feet).  Any airplane flights need to be either short, or aboard a charter airplane that can pressurize to a lower altitude.

Comment: We were around 35. I don't share your experience about stopping at every exit. Driving on motorways isn't exhausting.

Comment: It used to be possible to get a ferry from Scrabster, near Thurso, on the north coast of Scotland, to Bergen.  It was operated by [Smyril Line[(https://www.smyril-line.com/) and went via Tórshavn in the Faroes.  Unfortunately it stopped in 2008.

Answer (score 27):

They should really consider not taking their car further than Newcastle. That's 7 hours of driving.

From there it is the ferry to IJmuiden/Amsterdam, then trains to Hamburg (change at Osnabrück), arrive in Hamburg in the evening and directly hop onto the quite new direct sleeper train to Stockholm. They'll be in Stockholm at 9 in the morning well rested.

Comment: I assume that would have to be the night ferry? Or does the day ferry leave enough time to reach Hamburg?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is only a night ferry leaving at 5:30pm daily taking 16 hours. So they would sleep on the ferry and on the sleeper train.

Comment: You're probably right that they shouldn't drive, but this answer is an interesting reminder of US vs European attitudes towards driving. This trip is equivalent to driving from Chicago to Disneyland and that's something that Americans would accept for a big family vacation.

Comment: @Eugene More like a difference in options--ocean + great train system vs. no ocean + not great train system.

Comment: The downside of this approach is they won't have the car when they get there. Depending on what they plan to do when they get there and the nature of their medical issues that may or may not be a problem.

Comment: They can still rent a car if necessary.

Comment: @Sebastian Depending on several factors, e.g. how far in advance they could book it, the extra cost of taking a route that allows them to take a car, ... it may be more cost-effective to travel by car. Assuming that car travel in their destination is an absolute must.

Comment: Is an "autotrain" (US term - they put your car on the train, while you ride in a regular passenger car) an option? That would give them their own car at the destination. If they'll be staying a while, that would, likely, be significantly less expensive than renting a car if it's that critical.

Comment: "Hop onto.. direct sleeper train". That is very optimistic. The trains leaving from Hamburg to Stockholm require changes. Furthermore, there is a Stockholm-Hamburg night train, but what about seat reservations? I can say with certainty that it is not a matter of just "hopping on the next direct train" when travelling from Hamburg, through Denmark, to Sweden and up to Stockholm.

Comment: @Paulie-C I was only talking about the direct sleeper train.

Comment: It may be considerably cheaper to travel by passenger ferry and train - taking a car is often very expensive, with ferry fares, fuel, and possibly tolls, and there may be cheap deals for journeys combining ferry and train.

Comment: Yes, @Sebastian, and that is what I referred to as seen in my previous comment. Example: I just went to rail.cc and searched for direct overnight trains Hamburg- Stockholm for today, so "hop onto" as if I was in town and wanted to leave asap. "No offers available". My point is the same as before and this substantiates exactly that: It is not that simple to just get a last minute overnight train (that takes 17 hours), those trains are usually reserved in advance.

Comment: @Paulie-C They will probably not do such a journey ad-hoc. Furthermore, when I search for the night train on sj.se it will show as sold out today (Friday) but has berths available tomorrow (Saturday) as well as next week.

Answer (score 26):

That's not an easy trip.

**FERRY**

There are currently no ferries between the UK and Denmark, Norway or Sweden. That means you have to go through France, Belgium or the the Netherlands. If you want to maximize time on a boat, Newcastle->Amsterdam is probably your best choice. Boats are slow: that ferry takes about 16 hours and covers just a small fraction of the total distance. On the upside: it has restaurants, cabins, etc.

You will also have to get onto the Danish Main Island. With a car you will most likely have to take the ferry from Puttgarden to Rødby. Trains tend to go up north through Jutland and take the Great Belt Bridge. That's also an option for a car, but it's a big detour. Between Denmark and Sweden both cars and trains can take the Øresund bridge.

(more ferries from the comments and other answer).

Instead of Puttgarden/Rødby you can take Rostock to Trelleborg and bypass Denmark all together. Technically, you can also do Sassnitz to Ystad but that's too much of a detour.

**DRIVING.**

You can also use Google Maps for a direct driving direction. It's a LOT of driving and of course, non-UK Europe drives on the right side. The quickest route seem to go through the Channel Tunnel and than takes the Puttgarden/Rødby ferry (32 hours). You can avoid the car ferry by driving over the Great Belt Bridge (33 hours).

**TRAINS**

It's a rather convoluted trip. One option is to go from Skye to Inverness, Inverness to Paris and then Paris to Stockholm. Going through Paris is quite the detour, but it actually looks faster than getting off in Calais and taking the train from there.

**COMBOS**

You can certainly combine trains and ferries. You can take the train to Newcastle, ferry to Amsterdam and then train again to Stockholm.

**CONCLUSION**

This is a difficult trip that will require some planning. It will take multiple days and you probably want to put some overnight stop(s) in there to rest up. A lot of this depends on the nature of the medical condition and what your parents are comfortable doing (or not) in terms of driving (left and right), schlepping luggage, maneuvering train stations in different countries, long ferry rides on rough seas, etc.

Ferry Source: [https://ferrygogo.com/ferry-to-denmark-from-uk/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20there%20are%20currently%20no,to%20Denmark%20via%20The%20Netherlands](https://ferrygogo.com/ferry-to-denmark-from-uk/#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20there%20are%20currently%20no,to%20Denmark%20via%20The%20Netherlands).

Comment: Train to Brussels or Amsterdam might work better than Paris.

Comment: @Willeke: I though so to, but most faster seem to go through Paris

Comment: There's a [long running campaign](https://www.shetnews.co.uk/2018/10/18/renewed-call-for-norrona-to-return-to-isles/) for the [Faroes to Denmark ferry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smyril_Line) to call at Shetland which it passes within sight of. Were that ever to happen it would afford another route from the north of Scotland - although would require at least two long ferry journeys.

Comment: depending on the timing, travelling via Brussels, and taking a night train from Hamburg may be faster than changing in Paris

Comment: Is Eurostar currently still serving Calais Fretun?

Comment: @mdewey No, since the pandemic Eurostar aren't serving intermediate stations (Calais, Ashford, Ebbsfleet) between London and Lille. No future dates have been announced - they have said 'not in 2023'

Comment: @user1908704 indeed that was the information I had received too but was not sure.

Comment: There is a Newcastle →IJmuiden (for Amsterdam) ferry. The Rosyth (for Edinburgh) →Zeebrugge ferry by DFDS is meant to restart for spring this year, but DFDS aren't mentioning it

Comment: @Willeke: The problem with London-Amsterdam is that it's basically a dead end, as far as high-speed rail is concerned. Connections to Germany have been considered, but Germany is severely struggling with infrastructure investments (the freight rail connection to the Netherlands, scheduled for 2003 is currently projected for 2026 at the earliest!)

Comment: @MSalters, that is why I used the word might. In some rare cases it might allow for a connection while usually it does not.

Answer (score 18):

**The rail option**

The journey can be done by rail in about 36 hours.

[Various options from the UK to Sweden](https://www.seat61.com/Sweden.htm), the most plausible involves the Hamburg to Stockholm sleeper.  Unfortunately with the current timetable the connections are somewhat tight, but you can perhaps spend a day in Belgium or Germany to spread things out a bit.  Times below are for leaving on Monday 6th February 2023, from [Deutsche Bahn](https://www.bahn.com/)

1. Take the [Caledonian Sleeper](https://www.sleeper.scot/) from either Fort William or Inverness, leaving early evening.  If Inverness, a train from Kyle of Lochalsh adjacent to Skye takes about 2h30, eg Kyle 17.13 to Inverness 19.51. The Inverness sleeper departs 20.45.  Arrive London Euston about 07.45.
2. Take the 09.01 Eurostar 9116 to Bruxelles Midi, arriving 12.05 (beware that Eurostar currently have a 90 minute check in time, although you may get away with arriving slightly late)
3. Take the 13.25 Thalys 9435 to Koeln Hbf, arriving 15.15
4. Take the 16.04 ICE 1030 to Hamburg Altona, arriving 20.05
5. Take the 21.19 Euronight 346 to Stockholm Central, arriving 09.55

Comment: The actual Eurostat check in time is 30 minutes, the 90 minutes is the safe suggestion.

Comment: The main difficulty is that I think those are at least 3 separate tickets, meaning that if any is delayed, you'll need to re-book, and if the night train can't be caught, you're stuck in Hamburg

Comment: The [CIV COTIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIV_(rail_travel)) should cover missed connections, but it would be helpful to book all the tickets in one transaction via an agent to avoid any ambiguity. That said, the obligation to put you on the next train won't help much if that's a day later (or full), so building some slack in the schedule would be advised.

Answer (score 11):

Newcastle to IJmuiden, (also called to Amsterdam at times.)
Drive to Eemshaven and take the ferry to Kristiansand in Norway.

That will leave a longish drive in Scotland as well as one in Norway and Sweden.

Early booking is needed, especially for the ferry to Norway.

Comment: Good idea. I didn't think of this.

Comment: isn't that going to be a very long drive, from Kristiansand to Stockholm?

Comment: I guess it will be comparable to the drive in Scotland. But I have not done either so I am not sure.

Comment: Fun route (bit of a detour), but that's around 760 km from Kristiansand to Stockholm, which might not be ideal in an RHD car in winter.

Comment: It meets the requested 'no flying' .  I feel it is good to show more options. Additional options are not always better but may suit OP for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Drive from Skye to Newcastle (~7h). Take overnight ferry from Newcastle to IJmuiden. Drive from Ijmuiden to Travemünde (~6h) and take an overnight ferry to Malmö or Trelleborg and drive to Stockholm (~7h).

Comment: This actually answers the question! I would recommend to take the Rostock-Nynäshamn ferry instead. Less driving - more ferry! Nynäshamn is just south of Stockholm and it is a nice trip - I combined it with trains two times.

Comment: @froderik Not really, the Kristiansand route has less driving but one day with a longer drive. I read that Rostock-Nynäshamn might start again in 2024 so not an option for summer 2023.

Comment: Oh no they shut it down. Didn't know. Such a convenient way to get down to Europe from here....